# Close grand parent div jquery

Tags: jquery, hide, show

How can I hide a div when clicked on an "X" (closing glyphicon from FA) with jquery.

I already have a function to open a specific div which is a children of a div. How can I close it again?
How can I reach the "grandparent" of my div? I already tried parentsUntil() and closes() functions. 
Can you help me out?

Thank you in advance! ;)

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 
 $(".film").click(function (){
  $(this).children(".tag-cloud").fadeIn();
 });
 
 $(".fa-close").click(function () {
  $(this).parentsUntil("div").hide();
 });
 
});
```

```css
.tag-cloud {
 display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="film">
 <div class="row entry">
  <div class="col-md-2">
  
  <img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/fffabs/128.jpg" class="thumbnail">
  
  <span class="ckbox">
   <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox1">
   <label for="checkbox1"></label>
  </span></div>
  
  <div class="col-md-8">
  <h4 class="film-title">Film Title</h4>
  </div>
  
  <div class="col-md-2">
  <div class="rating pull-right">
  <i class="fa fa-star"></i><i class="fa fa-star"></i><i class="fa fa-star-half-full"></i><i class="fa fa-star-o"></i><i class="fa fa-star-o"></i>
  </div></div>
 
 </div> <!-- Row Ends -->
  <div class="tag-cloud">
   <ul>
   <li><a href="">tag1</a></li>
   <li><a href="">tag2</a></li>
   </ul>
  
  <div class="exit-tags">
   <i class="fa fa-2x fa-close">x</i>
  </div>
  </div><!-- tag-cloud -->
  
  </div><!-- film -->
```

Comment: You say 'grandparent', but specifically, which parent are you wanting to target?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure I understand the problem, but I think you want to use `.toggle()` or `hide()`.

Comment: Okay sorry this was a little misunderstanding.

Comment: I have a "div a" which includes a "div b" when i click on "div a" the "div b" should show up. when click on an x inside the "div b" this div should close.

Comment: the showing up of div b works with 
$(".film").click(function (){
  $(this).children(".tag-cloud").fadeIn();
 });
but i can´t close it without hide anything. i would like to close only the "div b" which is the cloud-tag div inside of the film div.